# C Programming malloc macro issue

Tags: c, macros, malloc

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:

Can I write this type of macro in C? I cannot get it to work myself.

```
#define MEM_ALLOC_C(type, nElements) (type = (type*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(type), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))
```

If I write it like this, it works:

```
#define MEM_ALLOC(type, nElements) (testFloat = (float*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))
```

This is how I am using it:

```
#define CACHE_ALIGNMENT 16
#define INDEX 7
#define MEM_ALLOC(type, nElements) (type = (float*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))
#define MEM_ALLOC_C(type, nElements) (type = (type*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(type), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))
#define MEM_DEALLOC_PTR(type) (_aligned_free(type))

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float* testFloat;

    //MEM_ALLOC_C(testFloat, INDEX);    // Problem here.

    MEM_ALLOC(testFloat, INDEX);        // works

    //testFloat = (float*)_aligned_malloc(INDEX * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT);  // works

    testFloat[0] = (float)12;

    //MEM_DEALLOC_PTR(testFloat);       // If we call de-alloc before printing, the value is not 12.
                                    // De-alloc seems to work?

    printf("Value at [%d] = %f \n", 0, testFloat[0]);

    getchar();

    MEM_DEALLOC_PTR(testFloat);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Return type from malloc() is void*, do not cast it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are correct of course. If I try to compile it on a C++ compiler, it will generate a error or warning. This is my logic for the cast inside the macro. And yes I should have specified that in the question. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think about the replacment:

```
type = (type*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(type), CACHE_ALIGNMENT)
```

becomes

```
testFloat = (testFloat*)_aligned_malloc(INDEX * sizeof(testFloat), CACHE_ALIGNMENT)
```

.

There is no such thing as `testFloat*`.

In pure C there is no need to cast the result of malloc. Therefore you can just do:

```
#define MEM_ALLOC_C(var, nElements) (var = _aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(*var), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))
```

Comment: You are correct, however the explanation by Michael Burr about lvalue and type is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1166780 the solution that I provide, however, is superior to the other suggested solution in that it requires fewer arguments with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your `MEM_ALLOC_C()` macro is that you're using the `type` parameter as both a type and a an lvalue. that can't work:

```
#define MEM_ALLOC_C(type, nElements) (type = (type*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(type), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))
//                                    ^^^^    ^^^^                                     ^^^^
//                                   lvalue   type                                     type
```

Note how in your working version you had to use a variable name where the lvalue goes and a type in the other spots.

If you really want to have a macro like this, why not just use it like a function and assign the result to a pointer instead of hiding the assignment inside the macro:

```
#define MEM_ALLOC_C(type, nElements) ((type*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(type), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))

testFloat = MEM_ALLOC_C(float, INDEX);
```

Comment: Yes of course, so simple, the explanation between type and lvalue is just what i needed. Now to just write it as MEM_ALLOC_C(testFloat, float, INDEX);

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But I'd prefer keeping the assignment outside of the macro since I think that makes it more obvious what's going on and there's no value in having it inside the macro (it doesn't even save you any typing except maybe a space or two).

Comment: To your additional comment: I am not sure if I need to hide it. How ever this version <br/>    #define MEM_ALLOC_C(var, type, nElements) (var = (type*)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(type), CACHE_ALIGNMENT))<br> Does not generate compiler warnings on C++, the other ones do (since they do not not have a cast), sure I could write the cast outside, but I am not sure which is better.